# Is there a way for a CoreBluetooth peripheral to deny a subscription to a central?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I have a peripheral that I'd like to protect against access by unwanted centrals. I haven't found a method that allows me to analyze a central before the central can subscribe.

Is there a method that does this?